# Python version not up-front in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, enthought

I no longer see the version of Python being used at the top of the Python window. What is the easiest way to find this out now?

- Thanks.

P.S. I now see that submitting a support email puts this information in the system info section, but coming from it always being printed up front in say idle, it is not as accessible. I guess I am questioning the design decision.

---

I guess I am really stating that I prefer having the Python version info as part of the Canopy welcome message :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in canopy installation. .ipython qt console is available in the editor

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
 with pylab-backend set to: qt
Type '?' for more information.

In [1]: sys.version
Out[1]: '2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Mar 25 2013, 15:38:39) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some options in the `sys` module, depending on whether you'd prefer human-readable or machine-readable:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) \n[GCC 4.4.5]'
>>> sys.version_info
(2, 6, 6, 'final', 0)
```